# Alt-Escape has different effect on different Win-XP machines

Tags: windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager

This is really weird.

On my desktop computer, I often use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd> to send the active window to the background. This is really useful for window management.

However, when I try pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Escape</kbd> on my new laptop, it does something similar but not identical: It sends the active window back, but not all the way to the background. i.e., instead of giving it the lowest index number, it just decrements its index number, probably by 1.

Both computers have the same Windows XP Professional.

Why is this? And how can I make my laptop computer send the active window to the background instead?

Comment: The desktop's behavior is described on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt-Tab#Behavior). Did the laptop, as probably all of them do, come with "helpful" utility software installed and running? Have you tried disabling all autostarts and background processes running as your user?

Comment: Is the behavior different for the same applications? Do all applications behave that way?

Answer (score 2):

Anything that interacts with the shell, either via a shell extension or a load hook in a .dll can cause it.

You can see and enable/disable these by using [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and [shellexview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html).

The simplest way to test if this is caused by some installed application, is to boot in Safe mode.
If Alt-Esc is then back to normal, this means that all that is left is to locate that application or shell extension.